# Get User Data, User to get the activity after splash screen based on the information provided while Signing Up using Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am doing a college project where students and teachers are using school data. I want teachers and students to have access to different data. I want teachers to send to home activity while students to main Activity. The user has already entered his type while Signing up. I want users to get specific activity based on user type. I am getting user-type data but not able to use it for other work.

Here is my code:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    var usertype: String? = null

    if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser != null) {

        var currentUser: String = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser.uid

        val DataBaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users")

        DataBaseReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(datasnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                usertype = datasnapshot.child(currentUser).child("type").getValue(String::class.java)
                usertype?.let { Log.d("usertype", it) }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            }
        })

        val utype = usertype.toString()
        Log.i("utype", utype)
        if (utype == "Student"){

            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
        else {
            val intent = Intent(this, home::class.java)
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

The Log result of user-type is a student but utype Log result is null. Now I want to get data of usertype from onDatachange to other function.

Comment: Now i just want to get data from usertype in utype

Answer (score 1):

> I am getting user-type data but not able to use it for other work.

This is happening because you are using the following if statement:

```
val utype = usertype.toString()
Log.i("utype", utype)
if (utype == "Student"){ ...}
```

Outside the callback. Firebase API is asynchronous. Any code that needs data from an asynchronous operation needs to be inside the "onDataChange()" method, or be called from there. So the simplest solution, in this case, is to move all the logic related to the above lines of code, in the "onDataChange()" method, inside the scope of `let`:

```
usertype = datasnapshot.child(currentUser).child("type").getValue(String::class.java)
    usertype?.let {
        Log.d("usertype", it)
        //Use your logic
    }
}
```

Comment: I am unable to use intent in it. I know that I should use callback in it but I am unable to implement it properly. Can you help me with it.

Comment: All the logic regarding the Intent should also be **moved** inside "onDataChange()" method. Give it a try and tell me if it works.